# Show that α is tautologically equivalent to β iff (α↔β) is a tautology?

Tags: logic

α|==|β iff |= (α↔β)

Does anyone know how to go about showing that this is true?

Comment: Truth table?${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

First, assume that $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is a tautology. Suppose that $g$ is some assignment of truth values to the relevant propositional variables. Since $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is true in this assignment, conclude that if $\alpha$ was true then $\beta$ is true, and vice versa.

In the other direction, assume that $\alpha$ is logically equivalent to $\beta$. Take some assignment $g$ and show that if $\alpha$ is false then $\beta$ is false, and so $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is true; and if $\alpha$ is true then $\beta$ is true, and so $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is true. These are the only two options, so $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is a tautology, as wanted.